# Django - Set a function(s) to be done in X seconds

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

I currently have a project where Users should be allowed to set up an action to be done by its own (even if there are no users online in the website) in X seconds, like Cron Jobs.

The thing is that those X seconds may be different for each users as well as the time start (it all depends on the user input for those values).

How would you do that in Django? Would you set some sort of Cron Jobs?

Comment: Yes, you should use cron jobs. Then determine whether the length of time will be set per user or per job. If per user, extend the User model to accept a field to hold a time interval. If per job, add a field to your Job model to accept the value.

Comment: Have a look at http://celeryproject.org/ it also offers a pypi package to integrate with Django. Although I'm not too sure about how to dynamically add scheduled items.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins in your opinion what should I do, set a Cron Job to check the DB field `time` every X sec to know if it needs to be done yet or not?

Comment: I would use something like django-cron and specify the time once when the job is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

- [django-cron](https://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) for repetitive task
- [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) for distributed tasks and supports scheduling.